# How to Move message/mail from folder Java IMAP Client

Tags: java, gmail, imap

I need to move messsage from an IMAP folder to another IMAP folder (of the same account) via Java.

I work on Gmail and the oauth login.

I use the java imap mail client: i fetch the message with sourceFolder.getMessages() and then I call the 
method `destFolder.appendMessages(sourceFolder.getMessages())` or `addMessages`: the problem born when the number of the messages to move is too big. I had the to move 8000 mail and  the login session expire after several minutes that the procedure has started to add but has not yet finished.

It process about 1 message for second.I use the oauth login

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to use server copy and delete.  In IMAP syntax, the copy command is `tag COPY sequence mailboxname`.  Like: `a000 COPY 1:* INBOX.Saved`, would copy all messages to my Saved subfolder.

The method you're doing requires each message to be downloaded then to reupload it.

Answer (score 0):

The IMAP [`MOVE` Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6851), specified in RFC 6851 from January 2013, introduced:

> two new commands, MOVE and UID MOVE, that are used to move messages from one mailbox to another.

It is supported by JavaEE's package [`com.sun.mail.imap`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#package.description):

> **MOVE Support**
>
> The IMAP MOVE extension (RFC 6851) is supported via the `IMAPFolder` methods [`moveMessages`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#moveMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-) and [`moveUIDMessages`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#moveUIDMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-).

See also:

- [move (copy) IMAPMessage to another folder on the mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888072/move-copy-imapmessage-to-another-folder-on-the-mail-server) - answer [using `IMAPFolder.moveMessages`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59137719/5730279)
- [IMAP: how to move a message from one folder to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122267/imap-how-to-move-a-message-from-one-folder-to-another) - illustrating the corresponding IMAP `MOVE` command