# Is there a way to move emails from one folder to another using javax.mail?

Tags: java

I'm developing an IMAP/SMTP client using `javax.mail` and would like to move certain emails from "INBOX" to another custom folder such as "MY_APPLICATION_FOLDER".

It seems possible to do something similar like copying from one folder to another, but it'd be desirable to be able to move the email entirely.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Folder.html)?

Comment: Move is copying and deleting. See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888072/move-copy-imapmessage-to-another-folder-on-the-mail-server) and use [`copyMessages()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#copyMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-) then delete the copied. This is also how you would use [IMAP to move messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122267/imap-how-to-move-a-message-from-one-folder-to-another).

Comment: Thanks @hc_dev! I'm posting an answer with the link you provided.

Comment: I marked this as duplicate and closed the question since you mentioned it you state that it answers your question.