# Move from inbox to archive using imaplib {outlook}

Tags: python, outlook, imaplib

I am going to move email from **inbox** to **archive** in **outlook** using **Python's** **imaplib** module.

```py
imap_server.store(email_id, '+FLAGS', 'Archive') # This does not raises an exception, but it has not result
```

```py
imap_server.store(email_id, '+FLAGS', '\Archive') # This raises an exception. <class 'imaplib.error'>
```

Whole idea is to **move** from **inbox** to **archive**. I can make **copy** operation, but not **move**.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Check these out: (a) [`outlook` library](https://github.com/awangga/outlook) and (b) [this discussion on github](https://gist.github.com/jdowner/1716927a367a575f4cc2).

Comment: Also, see this: [move-mail-in-imap-with-python-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776250/move-mail-in-imap-with-python-library).

Comment: I will check it.

Thanks !